# How to configure memory usage correctly for small job in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am getting OOMs with a fairly small job while running `pyspark` on `YARN`.

The job DOES get picked up by spark and yarn both, but then shortly after it fails with an OOM `Exit status: 52`:

```
ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on <ip>: Container marked as failed: containerID 2 on host: <ip>. Exit status: 52. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
```

And when I check the yarn log files for this application I see the following:

```
    date 19:03:19 INFO hadoop.ColumnChunkPageWriteStore: written 10,852B for [user] BINARY: 11,052 values, 11,764B raw, 10,786B comp, 1 pages, encodings: [BIT_PACKED, PLAIN_DICTIONARY, RLE], dic { 3,607 entries, 78,442B raw, 3,607B comp}
date 19:03:20 INFO mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: attempt_date1903_0006_m_000013_0: Committed
date 19:03:20 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 13.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 1058). 2077 bytes result sent to driver
date time:07 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 70.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 1115)
date time:07 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 127.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 1170)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/daemon.py", line 157, in manager
    code = worker(sock)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/daemon.py", line 61, in worker
    worker_main(infile, outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 136, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 545, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
date time:07 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue, since it seems like it is having trouble with the files but the spark driver memory is 8GB.

machines look like this:

```
21 nodes, 64GB each, 8 cores each
```

spark-defaults.conf is:

```
spark.executor.memory=30928mb
spark.driver.memory 8g
spark.executor.instances=30
spark.executor.cores = 7
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead = 19647
```

yarn-site.xml is:

```
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores = 1024
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 61430
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 61430
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 7 (left one for the driver)
```

Am I configuring anything incorrectly here?

Also, the spark UI is showing:

```
URL: spark://ip:7077
REST URL: spark://ip:6066
Alive Workers: 30
Cores in use: 240 Total, 0 Used
Memory in use: 1769.7 GB Total, 0.0 B Used
Applications: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Status: ALIVE
```

Any reason why the container would require more memory?  I am not sure whetehr to increase or decreases memory?

Comment: So you have 21 nodes and 8 cores each, that gives 168 CPU cores total. Leaving aside 1 core each aside for hadoop daemons , you have 147 cores available for each application, so with 7 parallel threads (tasks) per executor gives you 147/7 = 21 executors. And 1 executor is needed for application master. so 20 executors per 21 nodes ~=  1 executor per node.
So each node has 64GB RAM available and leave 1GB for OS and 7% of 63GB i.e. 4GB , you are still left with total 59GB RAM PER EXECUTOR. Why are you assigning only 30GB?

Comment: I meant 147 (cpu) cores / 7 (tasks i.e.) cores per executor = 21 executors

Comment: well, should I increase `spark.executory.memory`? Or increase `spark.executor.instances` so that the tasks are split up more?

Comment: try both by specifying `--executor-memory 59G` and `--num-executors 21` while submitting job using `spark-submit`. You dont have to modify conf file each time ..And I forgot to mention above 7% of 63GB is for yarn memory overhead. You currently have that at 20Gb, internally it always default to to max(384MB, .07 * spark.executor.memory).

Comment: okay, but also I need some room for `spark.driver.memory` so I have that set to 8G.  So I would have to subtract that from the `59GB` right?

Comment: Driver doesnt need 8GB on each node. Your driver memory can be your local machine from where you are submiting job , if you submit job in client mode, if you submiting application in cluster mode, driver will be one of 21 nodes.

Comment: And in yarn cluster mode, spark driver runs inside yarn application master, for which we are leaving aside entire 1 executor..so it can acquire upto 59gb on that executor. Unnecessary but it can...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 59 GB for executor +19 GB overhead will exceed the 61 GB allocated via yarn (See `yarn-site.xml` in my question).

Comment: See my 4th comment above regarding yarn memory overhead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142121/discussion-between-hunle-and-pushkr).

Comment: Is ` spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` inside the YARN container or outside the yarn container?  I don't understand where yarn is computing the physical memory limits when I get an OOM.

Comment: Can you write a complete answer @Pushkr and I can accept?    Also, I do not understand how the settings for `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 61430`
and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 61430` are correct?  Are both of those settings needed?